# Xamarin Forms: Letter spacing in Label Text

Tags: xamarin.forms, label, portable-class-library

Hi I am building an cross platform app using Xamarin forms PCL. In that app I need to add letter spacing to label text. 
I need space between label text characters. Is there any way to achieve this for all platforms. Letterspacing property is available in ANDROID but I need solution for all the platforms like ios, uwp, win8/8.1.

Comment: much better now that you've edited it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mureinik thanks I appreciate your input.

Comment: @Mureinik any help with this?

Comment: don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 11):

**Forms control**

```
public class LetterSpacingLabel : Label
{
    public float LetterSpacing { get; set; }
}
```

**The Android renderer** code looks like:

```
public class LetterSpacingLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected LetterSpacingLabel LetterSpacingLabel { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            this.LetterSpacingLabel = (LetterSpacingLabel)this.Element;
        }

        var letterSpacing = this.LetterSpacingLabel.LetterSpacing;
        this.Control.LetterSpacing = letterSpacing;

        this.UpdateLayout();
    }
}
```

**iOS renderer**

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        var data = Element as LetterSpacingLabel;
        if (data == null || Control == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var text = Control.Text;
        var attributedString = new NSMutableAttributedString(text);

        var nsKern = new NSString("NSKern");
        var spacing = NSObject.FromObject(data.LetterSpacing * 10);
        var range = new NSRange(0, text.Length);

        attributedString.AddAttribute(nsKern, spacing, range);
        Control.AttributedText = attributedString;
    }
```

The following code example demonstrates using the *LetterSpacingLabel* control:

```
< LetterSpacingLabel LetterSpacing="0.5" Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" />
```

The following screenshot show the label on [iOS](https://stayrony.github.io/images/LetterSpacingLabel/iphone7rosegold_portrait.png)

From post [here](https://stayrony.github.io/letter-spacing-label-in-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: See example code "Creating the Custom Renderer on iOS/Android" on page  [Custom Renderer / Customizing an Entry](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry) which shows the needed `using` declarations, and `[assembly: ExportRenderer( typeof( LabelRenderer ), typeof( LetterSpacingLabelRenderer ) )]` annotation. You may also need `using` declarations for 1) the `namespace` for `LetterSpacingLabel`, and 2) the `namespace` for `LetterSpacingLabelRenderer` (because the `assembly` annotation is above the namespace line, not "inside" the namespace).

Comment: CORRECTION: `[assembly: ExportRenderer( typeof( LetterSpacingLabel ), typeof( LetterSpacingLabelRenderer ) )]`

Answer (score 1):

Since version 4.4 Xamarin.Forms has now a `CharacterSpacing` property.