# Spacing for Label in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am learning the Xamarin Forms using XAML to create the interface for an app.

Is there any way to set the spacing between the text in Xamarin Forms?

I have tried to search for it on the xamarin website, but it only shows the solution using c#.

Comment: if you post a link to the solution you found, then we could possibly tell you how to translate it to XAML

Comment: Text spacing isn't really specific either. Do you mean text kerning like a label with adjustable space between the letters?

Comment: @Nick yes i mean the space between the letters in a label

Comment: You will need to create a class that extends the Label class, and then create custom renderers for each platform. Here is the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43667904/3183946

Comment: if your question involve xaml and not c#, why a c# tag ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a converter which takes string as value and add space between the letters in the Convert() method.

Comment: Can you show an example of what the code would look like?

Comment: // xaml code

// your converter code
public class StringToSpacedStringConverter : IValueConverter
 {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
   if (value == null)
   {
    return string.Empty;
   }

                       
   return spacedString;
  }

  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
   throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
 }

Comment: // xaml code
<Label  Text="{Binding Title,Converter{StaticResourcestringCaseConverter}">

// your converter code
public class StringToSpacedStringConverter : IValueConverter
 {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {                       
                       string spacedString = (string)value ?? string.Empty;

                       // your code to add space in  spacedString 

   return spacedString;
  }  
 }

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make custom renderers on each platform to add kerning to a label.

Forms control:

```
public class KerningLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty KerningProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Kerning), typeof(double), typeof(KerningLabel), 0d);

    public double Kerning
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(KerningProperty); }
        set { SetValue(KerningProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(KerningLabel), typeof(KerningLabelRenderer))]
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class KerningLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        private NSString _kerningAttribureName = new NSString("NSKern");

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null && Control != null)
            {
                SetKerning();
            }
        }

        private void SetKerning()
        {
            var element = Element as KerningLabel;
            string text = Element.Text;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                Control.Text = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                var attributedString = new NSMutableAttributedString(text);
                attributedString.AddAttribute(_kerningAttribureName, NSObject.FromObject(element.Kerning), new NSRange(0, text.Length - 1));
                Control.AttributedText = attributedString;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == Xaml.KerningLabel.KerningProperty.PropertyName ||
                e.PropertyName == Label.TextProperty.PropertyName ||
                e.PropertyName == Label.TextColorProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                SetKerning();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(KerningLabel), typeof(KerningLabelRenderer))]
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class KerningLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        public KerningLabelRenderer()
        {
            AutoPackage = false;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(e.NewElement != null && Control != null)
            {
                SetKerning();
            }
        }

        private void SetKerning()
        {
            var element = Element as KerningLabel;
            if (element != null && Control != null)
            {
                Control.Text = element.Text;
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                {
                    Control.LetterSpacing = (float)((element.Kerning) / 10.0f);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == Xaml.KerningLabel.KerningProperty.PropertyName ||
                e.PropertyName == Xaml.KerningLabel.TextProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                SetKerning();
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, the LetterSpacing property was only added in Android on devices Lollipop and up.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the **LineHeight** property of **Label** to set the height of a line as multiplier of the character size (as you know from Word or others). So it should look like this in **XAML**

```
<Label Text="Long text spanning at least 2 lines...", LineHeight = "1.5" />
```

and like this in **C#**

```
Label label = new Label { Text = "Long text spanning at least 2 lines...", LineHeight = 1.5 };
```